# I want fetch hostel data but shows error. Anyone has solution?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am creating application called as hostel management system using spring boot application using JPA repo.
I have added one hostel. then i added rooms, then update hostel to update join table entries.
Now I am trying to fetching hostel.
Unable to fetch hostel data, it shows :

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]

lots of line.............
```

I have uploaded this project on gitHub : https://github.com/aniketkadu0/hms_new.git

**Hostel.java**

```
@Table(name = "hostels")
public class Hostel implements Cloneable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int hostelId;
    String hostelName;
    String hostelAddress;
    String contactPersonName;
    String contactPersonNumber;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "hostel_id",
            referencedColumnName = "hostelId"
    ),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "room_number",
            referencedColumnName = "roomNumber"
    ))
    List<Room> rooms;
    @OneToOne
    Mess mess;
    @OneToMany
    List<Notice> notices;
    
}
```

**Room.java**

```
@Table(name = "rooms")
public class Room {
    
    @Id
    int roomNumber;
    int noOfOccupants;
    @OneToOne
    RoomDetail roomDetail;
    @OneToOne
    Hostel hostel;
    @OneToMany
    List<Student> student;
    
}
```

RoomDetail.java

```
@Entity
public class RoomDetail {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int roomDetailId;
    String roomName;
    int price;
    int maxOccupants;
}
```

**hostel JSON**

```
{
    "hostelId": 1,
    "hostelName": "Hostel no. 1 Boys Hostel",
    "hostelAddress": "building no. 5",
    "contactPersonName": "XYZ",
    "contactPersonNumber": "9999977777",
    "rooms": null,
    "mess": null,
    "notices": null
}
```

**Room JSON**

```
{
    "noOfOccupants" : 0,
    "roomDetail" : {
        "roomDetailId" : 1
    } ,
    "hostel" : {
        "hostelId" : 1
    }
}
```

AdminService.java

```
@Service
public class AdminService {

    @Autowired
    HostelDAO hostelDAO;
    @Autowired
    RoomDAO roomDAO;
    @Autowired
    RoomDetailDAO roomDetailDAO;

    public Hostel addHostel(Hostel hostel) {
        return hostelDAO.save(hostel);
    }

    public Room addRoom(Room room,int qty,int firstRoomNumber){
        
        Optional<Hostel> hostel = hostelDAO.findById(room.getHostel().getHostelId());   
        Optional<RoomDetail> roomDetail = roomDetailDAO.findById(room.getRoomDetail().getRoomDetailId());
        
        room.setHostel(hostel.get());
        room.setRoomDetail(roomDetail.get());
        
        List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();   
        room.setRoomNumber(firstRoomNumber);
        System.out.println(room);
                
        firstRoomNumber--;
        int i = 1;
        while( i <= qty) {
            Room newRoom = new Room(room.getRoomNumber(),
                                    room.getNoOfOccupants(),room.getRoomDetail(),
                                    room.getHostel(),room.getStudent());
            newRoom.setRoomNumber(firstRoomNumber + i);
            rooms.add(newRoom);
            i++;    
        }

        roomDAO.saveAll(rooms);
        hostel.get().setRooms(rooms);
        hostelDAO.save(hostel.get());
        return null;
    }

    public List<Hostel> getHostelData() {
        return hostelDAO.findAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: "at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser..............lots of lines " turns out the error is in that "lots of lines" so please include them in your post. Not even the first line itself is complete.

Comment: Somewhere in there with the stacktrace should be an actual error message you need to show us

Comment: there are lots of lines in error, I can't get the start lines of it.

Comment: Can anyone try running the spring boot application with these java files & give some solution? or can anyone figure out the java files that I shared?

Comment: If you can't post the error message itself, others really don't have the incentive to load your project and take the time to run it to debug it for you. If the error is repeating the same stack, chances are you are getting a StackOverflowException - common with JSON serialization when you have circular references. Tons of quesions/answers and even tutorials on this - set one side to JsonIgnore in bidirectional relationships. JPA serialization is to/from the database, and those annotations have nothing to do with and no control over JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with serializing a Hostel will be that your Hostel has rooms which point back at the same Hostel. There are many ways to tell your JSON serializer how to handle it. Assuming you are using Jackson, the easiest might be to add the @JsonIgnore annotation on one side that you don't need serialized. Ie:

```
@Table(name = "rooms")
public class Room {
    
    @Id
    int roomNumber;
    int noOfOccupants;
    @OneToOne
    RoomDetail roomDetail;
    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    Hostel hostel;
    @OneToMany
    List<Student> student;   
}
```

You will have to look at all your circular references - the entire graph really - and decide what you really want serialized when fetching through REST calls, and how your clients might need to handle the data.

Comment: It's working now! but now when I am adding a room with hostelId , it is not saving hostelId in database

Comment: If the room.hostel is set to jsonIgnore, it will be null when you deserialize a Room from your Rest client. If you are passing in a hostelId (if it is a rest resource, it probably should be in the path ie /v1/hostel/<id>/room), you'll need to use it to look up the hostel to fix the reference for JPA to save it.